# Apache Basic authentication not working

Tags: apache

I have a basic `HTTP://x.x.x.x/repository`. I am trying to implement basic authentication on this using Apache. I have added below config in `httpd.conf` and then restarted Apache but still no authentication is there when I access `HTTP://x.x.x.x/repository` using browser.

```
<Location "http://x.x.x.x/repository/">
  AuthUserFile /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd
  AuthName "My Realm"
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@email.address.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/httpd/htdocs"
    ServerName yourdomain.com


    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass /repository/ ajp://localhost:8009/repository/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location

> The enclosed directives will be applied to the request if the path
>   component of the URL meets any of the following criteria:
>
> 1. The specified location matches exactly **the path component** of the URL.
> 2. The specified location, which ends in a forward slash, is a prefix of the path component of the URL (treated as a context root).
> 3. The specified location, with the addition of a trailing slash, is a prefix of the path component of the URL (also treated as a context root).

so you need to remove "http://x.x.x.x" from your path in *Location* node

Comment: I tried by removing HTTP://x.x.x.x  from location node and restarted apache still no authentication window is available on accessing HTTP://x.x.x.x/repository/

Comment: Do you have apache **mod_auth_basic**, **mod_authn_file** and **mod_authz_user** enabled?

Comment: Yes all these are in place and enabled.